# How to look at two columns and delete duplicates in second column

Tags: excel, vba, macros, copy, duplicates

I'm trying to write a code that will allow me to look at two very similar columns, and clear the cell of the duplicate in the second column if it already exists in the first column.  I have a code that is sort of working, but it is deleting some of the duplicates and moving them upwards, but I want them to remain in their original cell.  I essentially want it to say "if the cell exists in column1 and column 2, clear the cell in column 2".  I'm not sure if this is possible.  Here is the code I have been working with. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub CopyPasteHistorical()

CopyPasteHistorical Macro

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Columns("D:D").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
'remove duplicates
Columns("C:D").Select
Dim duplicates As Range
Set duplicates = Selection
Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want them to remain where they are you will need to loop through and use either Find or MATCH to see it there is a match then clear the contents if a match is found.

Comment: Do you know what an example code of this would look like? I'm still new to VBA so I'm not sure how to execute that.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go the opposite way, like following (commented) code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPasteHistorical()
    Dim sht1Rng As Range, cell As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- reference Sheet1
        Set sht1Rng = .Range("I1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<-- set range with its column "I" cells containing constant (i.e. not formulas) values
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet2") '<-- reference Sheet2
        For Each cell In sht1Rng '<-- loop through Sheet1 range
            If cell.Value <> .Cells(cell.Row, "C") Then .Cells(cell.Row, "D") = cell.Value '<-- if sheet1 current cell content is different from Sheet2 column "C" cell content in the same row then write it in Sheet 2 column "D" corresponding row
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

this way you:

- only bother with Sheet1 column "I" relevant cells (i.e. not blank ones)
- don't make unnecessary copy&paste
- only write wanted values in Sheet2

Comment: this worked very well, thank you! another quick question, say I have to do this more than once, and I want it to check again for changed values but not erase any historical comments in the back sheet, is there something I could add onto this that will only copy the new value from the reference sheet over if the cell is empty and if it is not, copy it over to the column to the right, etc.  Thank you again!!

Comment: You are welcome. Please, as per this site rules: 1) any new issue must be asked with new post. it'd help you showing your code and efforts  2) since I fulfilled your _original_ question then please mark answer as accepted. thank you

Answer (score 1):

To do what Scott is talking about, you can try the following:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'get the last row of the 1st column, "A" in this case
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


    Dim i As Integer
    'loop through all the rows of column A
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        'get value of cell, find and replace with "" in column "B"
        Dim curVal
        curVal = ws.Range("A" & i).Value
        ws.Columns("B").Replace _
            What:=curVal, Replacement:="", _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
    Next i


End Sub
```

This will replace the duplicates in column B with a blank instead of deleting/shifting upwards.